# UITapGesture recognise tap only border wise of UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

Here is the code:

This section is written on `**-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageDispalyFullScreenTapped:)];
                singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                singleTap.delegate=self;
                cell.imgDisplay.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                [cell.imgDisplay addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Next I have implemented the delegate, i.e. `**UIGestureRecognizerDelegate**`

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
```

Now implemented the selector when UIImageView getting tapped

```
-(void)imageDispalyFullScreenTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    UIView *tappedView = gesture.view;
    UITableViewCell *cell=[self getSuperViewOfType:[UITableViewCell class] FromView:tappedView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[tblChat indexPathForCell:cell];
    Sock_ModelChat *objChat=[arrDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([objChat.strUrlLocal stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]].length>0) {
        imgSelectedDisplay=[[Sock_DB sharedInstance] getImageForName:objChat.strUrlLocal];

        ImageDisplayerViewController *imageDisplayer=[ImageDisplayerViewController sharedInstance];
        imageDisplayer.delegate=self;
        [self addChildViewController:imageDisplayer];
        imageDisplayer.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds), CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds));
        [self.view addSubview:imageDisplayer.view];
        [imageDisplayer didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
}
```

But the problem is whenever tapping on the border side or edge side of the image view, the tap on image view getting detected and the selector **imageDispalyFullScreenTapped** fired.But when tapping on the center or near the center, tap is not getting detected and so the related selctor also not firing.

I am working on XCode Version 8.0 (8A218a) and iOS 10.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be UserInteraction is disabled in your case

then you can add gesture like :

```
let gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target:self, action:#selector(handleTap))
gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
gesture.delegate = self
cell.imageView?.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

then add below function in your viewcontroller

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {}
```